# Config of Magento not work

Tags: magento

This is my code on config.xml of Basetut modules on Magento.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <!--Version của module-->
      <Basetut_Memberlog>
         <version>0.1.1</version>
      </Basetut_Memberlog>
   </modules>

   <!--Khai báo admin router-->
   <admin>
      <routers>
         <memberlogadmin>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
               <module>Basetut_Memberlog</module>
               <frontName>memberlogadmin</frontName>
            </args>
         </memberlogadmin>
      </routers>
   </admin>
   <adminhtml>
      <!-- Khai báo file layout trong admin-->
      <layout>
         <updates>
            <memberlog>
               <file>memberlog.xml</file>
            </memberlog>
         </updates>
      </layout>
   </adminhtml>
   <frontend>
      <routers>
         <memberlog_list>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
               <module>Basetut_Memberlog</module>
               <frontName>memberlog_list</frontName>
            </args>
         </memberlog_list>
      </routers>
      <default>
            <router>memberlog_list</router>
      </default>
      <layout>
         <updates>
            <memberlog_list>
               <file>memberlog.xml</file>
            </memberlog_list>
         </updates>
      </layout>
   </frontend>
   <global>
      <!--Khai báo model, resource model-->
      <models>
         <memberlog>
            <class>Basetut_Memberlog_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>memberlog_mysql4</resourceModel>
         </memberlog>
         <memberlog_mysql4>
            <class>Basetut_Memberlog_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
               <log>
                  <table>memberlog</table>
               </log>
            </entities>
         </memberlog_mysql4>
      </models>
      <!--Khai báo resource để connect và thao tác với database được-->
      <resources>
         <memberlog_setup>
            <setup>
               <module>Basetut_Memberlog</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
               <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
         </memberlog_setup>
         <memberlog_write>
            <connection>
               <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
         </memberlog_write>
         <memberlog_read>
            <connection>
               <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
         </memberlog_read>
      </resources>
      <!--Khai báo block để có thể dùng được-->
      <blocks>
         <memberlog>
            <class>Basetut_Memberlog_Block</class>
         </memberlog>
      </blocks>
      <!--Khai báo helper-->
      <helpers>
         <memberlog>
            <class>Basetut_Memberlog_Helper</class>
         </memberlog>
      </helpers>
   </global>
</config>
```

I had a controller with name is MemberController. When i type this link http://localhost/magento/index.php/memberlog_list on address. It does not work. I don't know why. What wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code

```
..........
 <frontend>
  <routers>
     <memberloglist>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
           <module>Basetut_Memberlog</module>
           <frontName>memberloglist</frontName>
        </args>
     </memberloglist>
  </routers>
  <default>
        <router>memberloglist</router>
  </default>  
 </frontend> 
 ...........
```